# Web service created with JAX-WS wsimport failing on AIX tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws, aix, wsimport

I have a jar file which houses client code to connect to our infrastructure webservices that was initially created using axis' wsdl2java.  I converted the guts of the connectivity this week to use the extract from wsimport.  When running on my local Windows XP tomcat using java6_18 I have no issues and all runs perfectly.  I have now moved my code to our development AIX instance and have lost total web service communication while receiving the following error:

```
XML reader error: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: 
The root element is required in a well-formed document
```

On AIX we are running java6_64.

I am assuming it is the AIX java libs not being compatible with the Sun provided java runtime libs however I am at a total loss at the moment as to how to resolve.

Can anybody shed some light on why I am receiving this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like answering my own question but thought recording the answer could be beneficial to others...

After digging a bit, the resolution was simply the format of the wsdl url.  With axis, I specified the wsdl URL as the path to the webservice.  For JAX-WS, it requires path to the service+"?wsdl" (the actual wsdl to load at runtime).

The above error was generated since the "axis" path did not result in the wsdl to pull but rather a blank resultset.  Once I added the "?wsdl" all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a code page issue as it complains that there is no root-element, and if the `<` character is misinterpreted as something else you have no root element.

Check the system properties to see what encoding the program runs under.  You may have an assumption somewhere that the encoding is ISO-Latin-1 as under Windows.